# Remove multiple item from 2 dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i need to write a code in python that remove multiple items in dictionary by indexing
I have 1 dictionary and 1 set:

The dictionary is :

```
{'Page': ['2', '0-50', '0', '0-20', '0-20'], 'PageSize': [1, 50, 1, 20, 20]}
```

the  Set is :

```
{3, 4}
```

I want to create a new dictionary that remove the indexing from the Set

So the final dictionary should look like this :

```
{'Page': ['2', '0-50', '0'], 'PageSize': [1, 50, 1]}
```

Comment: The second is not a dictionary but a set. Is it always `{3, 4}`?

Comment: Sorry , changing it now , but no , it change , the main propose is to delete multi values from dict.

Comment: your first dict is too long, please summarize your problem with a more readable example.

Comment: When I read your question, it looks like your dict_2 is useless.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
data = <Your first dictionary>
indicesto_remove = <your set of indices>

data = {
    k, [v for i, v in enumerate(d) if i not in indices_to_remove] 
    for k, d in data.items()
}
```

It iterates over entries in your dictionary and filters out the values from the lists that have indices specified in your set.

Also note, if your indices have some simpler structure you can have simpler solutions. For example, to remove the last two values you can instead use `d[:-2]`.